# On sum of arithmetic functions $\mu(n) / \phi(n)$ and $\mu(n) \log(n) / \phi(n)$.

Tags: analytic-number-theory

On *Multiplicative number theory : Classical theory* *(Montgomery, Vaughan)* pp.185, there is an exercise concerning sums below.

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)}{\phi(n)} = 0 $$
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\mu(n)\log(n)}{\phi(n)} = 0$$

They say these formulas can be proved by same method as they proved the PNT.

I think I can get some asymptotic bound for
$$ \sum_{n \le x}\frac{\mu(n)}{\phi(n)} $$
$$ \sum_{n \le x}\frac{\mu(n)\log(n)}{\phi(n)} .$$

if I follow the solution of this exercise.

I'm curious about above asymptotic bounds.

Actually authors quoted  *Hardy, G. H. (1921). Note on Ramanujan’s trigonometrical function c_q(n), and certain
series of arithmetical functions, Proc. Cambridge Philos. Soc. 20, 263–271*, 
but it's unable to find on internet.

Answer (score 0):

I am a beginner in this branch of mathematics so please feel free to correct any mistakes.

We have $$\begin{align}\sum_{n\le x}\frac{\mu(n)}{\phi(n)}&=\sum_{n\le x}\left(\mu(n)\sum_{d\mid n}\frac1{\mu(d)}\frac dn\right)=\sum_{n\le x}\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{d\mu(n)}{n\mu(d)}\\&=\sum_{d\le x}\sum_{q\le x/d}\frac{\mu(q)}q=\mathcal{O}\left(\sum_{d\le x}\sum_{q\le x/d}\frac1q\right)\\&=\mathcal{O}\left(\sum_{d\le x}\log\frac xd+C+\mathcal{O}\left(\frac dx\right)\right)\\&=\mathcal{O}\left(\sum_{d\le x}\log\frac xd\right)\\&=\mathcal{O}\left(\log x\right)\end{align}$$

Comment: Thank you for answering. I can't quite understand the second equation on line 1, i.e. $\mu(n) \sum_{d|n} \mu(d) n / d = \sum_{d|n} d\mu(n) / n\mu(d) $ .

Comment: I think on line 1, $\sum_{d|n} \mu(d)n/d$ is expansion for $\phi(n)$ , not $1/ \phi(n)$.

Comment: Corrected! ${}{}$